# Get subView's containing view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

If I have a view (`mainView`) in which I have added subViews. How do I get to subviews instance to mainView ?

I have a button in those subviews which when pressed should call a method in mainView, so I tried:

```
[myButton addTarget:self.presentingViewController
             action:@selector(myMethod:)
 forControlerEvents:UIControletcetc];
```

and

```
[myButton addTarget:self.parentViewController action:@selector....];
```

I read that `parentViewController` now returns `nil` in iOS 5, but `presentingViewController` doesn't seem the way to do it because its not presented modally. Its just a subview. Any hints?

Comment: actually, those subViews are outlets in mainView

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make it quite clear whether you are talking about views or view controllers. Use the `superview` property to access a view's parent.

There is generally no way to get from a view to its view controller.

Comment: I want to access the subviews parent view controllers

Comment: superView returns a UIView, I need it to return the mainView's view controller... so it should be UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

It feels to me that you're trying to let your views know about objects beyond their scope.

If you need to notify about an event to anyone that included your view, you could use a **delegate** to do that.

Say:

```
@protocol YourClassDelegate

@optional

- (void)instanceOfYourClass:(YourClass *)instance tappedButton:(UIButton *)button;

@end
```

and then

```
@interface YourClass

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<YourClassDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

I hope you can take it from here, by synthesizing the property, assigning the delegate and calling the method when you need to.